# ng-table $scope.tableParams.reload() not working

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am new to angularjs and ng-table, I am adding a new entry into ngtable. inside the success callback, trying to reload the ng-table using **$scope.tableParams.reload();**, I got the following error: **TypeError: j.$scope is null
e/this.reload/<()....** .

sample program attached here.

HTML:

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>Row 1</tr>
            <tr>Row 2</tr>
            <tr>Row 3</tr>
            <tr>Row 4</tr>
            <tr>Row 5</tr>
            <tr>Row 6</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td sortable="'value1'">{{user.value1}}</td>
                <td sortable="'value2'">{{user.value2}}</td>
                <td sortable="'value3'">{{user.value3}}</td>
                <td sortable="'value4'">{{user.value4}}</td>
                <td sortable="'value5'">{{user.value5}}</td>
                <td sortable="'value6'">{{user.value6}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save"  ng-click="save_details()">Save changes</button>
```

Controller :

//loading data from server

```
    (function(){
        var Api = $resource('/portal/api/visa/'+id);
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first pagez
            count: 10,          // count per page
            sorting: {
                name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
            }
        }, {
            total: 0,           // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                // ajax request to api
                Api.get(params.url(), function (data) {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        // update table params
                        params.total(data.total);
                        // set new data
                        $defer.resolve(data.result);
                        console.log(data.result);
                    }, 10);
                });
            }
        });
    }());
```

Save function :

```
    $scope.save_details = function() {
        $http.post('/portal/api/visa/', $scope.save_data).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data) {
                console.log("Details Saved Successfully");
            } else {
                console.log("Details Saved Failed... Try again");
            }
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });
    };
```

Comment: If I undestand you correctly, you want to refresh the data after post?

Comment: arman @ yes. but I found the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Deepakraj where you found the answer?

Comment: @Claudio Pomo $scope.tableParams.reload(). I am using this line to reload the table after a callback function. My html  like this
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table"><tr><td>Row 1</td></tr></table>